# Matches in color, others just shown

Tags: grep, color

I'm just trying to get grep to show all the lines, but the ones that match should have the matching text colored. 
Specifically I need this for something like this:

```
tail -f file.log | grep --color Exception
```

Unfortunately I don't see any option in grep that would simultaneous show the not matching lines and the lines that match (with color).
Is there any other tool for this in unix/linux that would allow this?

Answer (score 1):

One work-around would be to use the context option with a large line count:

```
tail -f file.log | grep -C 1000 --color Exception
```

If you have [`ack`](http://petdance.com/ack/) it has an option for this:

```
tail -f file.log | ack --color --passthru Exception
```